# Spacy retrain from last trained models (online learning)

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, spacy

I'm using TextCatCNN from SpaCy to solve a text classification problem. I Just prepared train, test and validation data and start training a model with the default configuration file generated by the training command:

```
python -m spacy init config --pipeline textcat <config_out_path>
```

```
[paths]
train = null
dev = null
vectors = null
init_tok2vec = null

[system]
gpu_allocator = null
seed = 0

[nlp]
lang = "en"
pipeline = ["textcat"]
batch_size = 1000
disabled = []
before_creation = null
after_creation = null
after_pipeline_creation = null
tokenizer = {"@tokenizers":"spacy.Tokenizer.v1"}
vectors = {"@vectors":"spacy.Vectors.v1"}

[components]

[components.textcat]
factory = "textcat"
scorer = {"@scorers":"spacy.textcat_scorer.v2"}
threshold = 0.0

[components.textcat.model]
@architectures = "spacy.TextCatBOW.v2"
exclusive_classes = true
ngram_size = 1
no_output_layer = false
nO = null

[corpora]

[corpora.dev]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.dev}
max_length = 0
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[corpora.train]
@readers = "spacy.Corpus.v1"
path = ${paths.train}
max_length = 0
gold_preproc = false
limit = 0
augmenter = null

[training]
dev_corpus = "corpora.dev"
train_corpus = "corpora.train"
seed = ${system.seed}
gpu_allocator = ${system.gpu_allocator}
dropout = 0.1
accumulate_gradient = 1
patience = 1600
max_epochs = 0
max_steps = 20000
eval_frequency = 200
frozen_components = []
annotating_components = []
before_to_disk = null
before_update = null

[training.batcher]
@batchers = "spacy.batch_by_words.v1"
discard_oversize = false
tolerance = 0.2
get_length = null

[training.batcher.size]
@schedules = "compounding.v1"
start = 100
stop = 1000
compound = 1.001
t = 0.0

[training.logger]
@loggers = "spacy.ConsoleLogger.v1"
progress_bar = false

[training.optimizer]
@optimizers = "Adam.v1"
beta1 = 0.9
beta2 = 0.999
L2_is_weight_decay = true
L2 = 0.01
grad_clip = 1.0
use_averages = false
eps = 0.00000001
learn_rate = 0.001

[training.score_weights]
cats_score = 1.0
cats_score_desc = null
cats_micro_p = null
cats_micro_r = null
cats_micro_f = null
cats_macro_p = null
cats_macro_r = null
cats_macro_f = null
cats_macro_auc = null
cats_f_per_type = null

[pretraining]

[initialize]
vectors = ${paths.vectors}
init_tok2vec = ${paths.init_tok2vec}
vocab_data = null
lookups = null
before_init = null
after_init = null

[initialize.components]

[initialize.tokenizer]
```

After evaluating I get some metrics and everything is OK. The problem comes when time pass and new data samples are generated (I simulated it by generating two training sets). I just want to "update the weights" of my model in order to include variance of new data. This is called online learning.

I tried by changing `factory = "textcat"` by `source = "<model_folder>/model-best"` in `[components.textcat]` section but when train with the second bunch of data, loss function values are equal to the first training process, so it is not performing online learning. Also, when predicting with the second set of data, metrics are equal or worse.

How can I perform online learning with SpaCy's TextCatCNN, suppossing it is possible?

Comment: The optimizer state is not currently saved with the model, so when you update a model using `source`, the optimizer starts from the same settings as if you were training from scratch. (This is a feature request currently on the back burner.)